# Notepad ++ Make from 1,2,3,4 to 3,4

Tags: notepad++

I have text in this format:

```
test1,test2,test3,test4
```

they are separated by `,` .

How can I delete

```
test1,test2
```

and leave only

```
test3,test4
```

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I delete `test1,test2` and leave only `test3,test4`?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)`
- Set "Replace with" to `\3,\4`
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
test1,test2,test3,test4
```

After:

```
test3,test4
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Yea but the thing is there are differnet words example

number,phonenumber,name,surname
I just want to keep 
name,surname

Comment: @blake The thing is it works for any 4 phrases separated by commas. Try it and see.

Comment: @blake Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+,([^,]+,[^,]+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    .+              # 1 or more any character
    ,               # a comma
    (               # start group 1
        [^,]+       # 1 or more non comma
        ,           # a comma
        [^,]+       # 1 or more non comma
    )               # end group
$                   # end of line
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]